# repeated string problem in hackerrank getting time limits problem

Tags: java

I am solving the repeated string hackerrank problem. but all the test cases are not running may be my logic is not correct.The problem is like that

[image: repeated string problem]

my code is given below which consists of repeatedString and countingA functions having no of variables 
i,a,and infinity String   ...

```
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

    // Complete the repeatedString function below.
    static long repeatedString(String s, long n) {
        long i=1;
        String infinityString="";
        while(s.length()*i<=n)
        {
            infinityString+=s;
            i++;
        }
        if(s.length()%infinityString.length()==0){
           return countingA(infinityString); 
        }else{
            infinityString+=s.substring(0,(s.length()%infinityString.length())-1);
            return countingA(infinityString); 
        }
    }
    public static long countingA(String infinity)
    {   
        long a=0;
        for(int i=0;i<infinity.length();i++)
        {
            if(infinity.charAt(i)=='a')
            {
                a++;
            }
        }
        return a;
    }

    private static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(System.getenv("OUTPUT_PATH")));

        String s = scanner.nextLine();

        long n = scanner.nextLong();
        scanner.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?");

        long result = repeatedString(s, n);

        bufferedWriter.write(String.valueOf(result));
        bufferedWriter.newLine();

        bufferedWriter.close();

        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the case you are missing is condition when `n%s!=0` then you need to count the extra a's.  I have also solved this problem in c++ and used the following logic

```
  static int numberOfAs(String s,long len){
        int val=0;
        for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
            if(s.charAt(i)=='a'){
                val++;
            }
        }
        return val;
    }

    static long repeatedString(String s, long n) {

        int size = s.length();
        int noA = numberOfAs(s,s.length());// 1
        double val = Math.floor(n/size);
        if(s.length()%n==0){ // 2
            return noA*(long)val;
        }else{
            long countedA = (long)val * noA; //3
            long valsLeft = n-(long) (val*size); //4
            long letfA = numberOfAs(s,valsLeft); //5
            long ans = countedA + letfA; //6
            return ans;
        }
    }
```

1. count number of a's in the provided string i.e `s`
2. Condition when string `s` is a multiple of total count `n` so you just need to multiply the number of a's in `s` with the result of `n/s`.
3. Is the total number of a's present in the `n/s`.
4. extra string after divisibility, we need to calculate the a's separately for this.
5. Calculated a's separately for extra string.
6. return their sum.

Hope this helps

Comment: can u change to java ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this,

```
static long countA(String s, long n) {
    long totalCount = 0;
    long aCount = 0;
    long times = n / s.length();

    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {    
        if(s.charAt(i) == 'a')    
            aCount++;    
    }
    totalCount =  times * aCount;
    aCount = 0;
    if(n%s.length() != 0) {
        for(int i=0;i<n - (times * s.length());i++)
            aCount++;
    }
    return totalCount + aCount;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is even in normal code too slow because of the string concatenation allocating a larger string.

```
    String infinityString = "";
    while (s.length()*i <= n) {
        infinityString += s;
        i++;
    }

    StringBuilder infinityStringB = new StringBuilder();
    while (s.length()*i <= n) {
        infinityStringB.append(s);
        i++;
    }
    String infinityString = StringBuilder.toString();
```

Also one would like:

```
    StringBuilder infinityStringB = new StringBuilder((int) n);
```

And there one sees: String cannot hold long n chars.

However you do not need the repeated string:

```
if (s.isEmpty()) {
    return 0;
}
long repititions = n / s.length();
int remaining = (int)(n % s.length());
String remainder = s.substring(0, remaining);

return countAs(s) * repetitions + countAs(remainder);
```